# ASP.NET Changing the active class in list-group anchor tag

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4, master-pages

I have a MasterPage in ASP.NET webforms application where i designed layout. Here it is

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="list-group ">
                            <a href="UserProfile.aspx" id="dashboard" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">Dashboard</a>
                            <a href="AddEmployeeFather.aspx" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Add Employee Father</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Search User</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Print Information</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Change Password</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Logout</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

On load, the UserProfile.aspx has an active class which is highlighted. Now i want that if i click on AddEmployeeFather.aspx, this this list item become active. this is my jqyery code

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
                var url = window.location;
                $('.list-group .list-group-item').find('.active').removeClass('active');
                $('.list-group .list-group-item a').each(function () {
                    if (this.href == url) {
                        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            });
```

I don't know where is the problem. please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.location is an object. Use window.location.href.

Then you can find the link with the same url and set active class on the link

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    $('a.list-group-item').each(function () {
        if (this.href == url) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            return false; // exit the loop
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It didn't work for me although i add the following code block

`$("a#dashboard").addClass("active");
            $("a").click(function(){
      $("a").removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
        });`
It highlight the list item for a second but then it vanish. I think when the page loads, it give the active class to the top list item. what am i missing here?

Comment: Yes, on click of the link it adds the class to it, and since default behaviour isn't prevented the document is loaded with the url

Comment: yeah i guess. why it works if i remove the actual url and put # instead. Please help me out here.

Comment: Please check updated code. There was an error in the selector which is corrected now...